# How do I automatically clear an attribute in a struct when it is moved?

Tags: rust

I have a struct

```
struct Test {
    list: Vec<u64>
}
```

and method in which I would like to get vector and erase list field to empty Vec

```
fn get_list(&self) -> Vec<u64> {
    let list = Vec::new();
    for item in self.list.drain() {
        list.push(item);
    }
    list
}
```

It there another approach for doing it? Something like autoreinit field on moving value, for example:

```
fn get_list(&self) -> ???<Vec<u64>> {
    self.list
}
```

Comment: Both of your `get_list` examples need to take `self` by `&mut`, otherwise you cannot modify the `list` field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution, you can test on Rust playground (sadly share button doesn't work for me atm).

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
   list: Vec<u64>
}

impl Test {

    fn get_list(&mut self) -> Vec<u64> {
       let repl = mem::replace(&mut self.list, Vec::new());
       repl
    }

}

fn main() {
    let mut r = Test {
       list : vec![1,2,3]
    };
    print!("r : {:?} ", r);
    print!("replace : {:?} ", r.get_list());
    print!("r : {:?} ", r);
}
```

You just need to run `mem::replace`([docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/mem/fn.replace.html)) on a mutable value and replace it with a value that will be moved in its place. In this case our destination is `self.list` and value we are replacing it is a blank `Vec`.

Things to note:

- Field `self.list` of Test, needs to be taken as `&mut self.list`.
- Previous change implies that `self` should be mutable as well.
- **Second parameter of replace is moved**. That means it won't be available for further after this call. What this usually means, you either pass it a Vec constructor (e.g. `Vec::new()`) or clone of value that's replacing.

Answer (score -1):

From #rust IRC

< theme> jiojiajiu, http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/mem/fn.replace.html

Comment: Please provide more than just a link for an answer. Explain why this does what you need.